# Getting array of objects in laravel blade

Tags: php, laravel-5.4

Am developing a website like Olx.
I want to append the main categories and sub categories in menu bar.
Am getting the return object like this for each element:
[image]

My controller code is:

```
$all_categories = [];
        $main_categories_name = Category::where('parent_id', 0)->pluck('name')->toArray();
        $main_categories_id = Category::where('parent_id', 0)->pluck('id')->toArray();        
        foreach($main_categories_id as $id){
          $name = Category::where('id', $id)->pluck('name');
          $sub_categories = Category::where('parent_id', $id)->pluck('name')->toArray();
          $all_categories[] = array('name' => $name, 'sub_categories' => $sub_categories);
        } 
        return $all_categories;
```

How do I get these elements in blade?

```
@foreach($all_categories as $category) 
                @foreach($category['name'] as $category) 
                  <li id="{{$category}}" name="{{$category}}" class="dropdown-submenu main_category"> <a class="maincategory" tabindex="-1" href="#"><span class="categoryname">{{$category}}</span></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                      <li class="subcategory" id="subcat"> sub_category
                      </li>
                    </ul>
                  </li>
                @endforeach
            @endforeach
```

I used like this. Now I want sub_categories in the name where I mentioned sub_category.

Am getting like this:
[image]

After using this code:

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu multi-level">
            @foreach($all_categories as $category)                 
              <li id="{{$category['name']}}" name="{{$category['name']}}" class="dropdown-submenu main_category"> <a class="maincategory" tabindex="-1" href="#"><span class="categoryname">{{$category['name']}}</span></a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                @foreach($category['sub_categories'] as $category) 
                  <li class="subcategory" id="subcat"><a href="#">{{$category}}</a></li>
                @endforeach
                </ul>
              </li>
            @endforeach
            </ul>
```

What to do for this? Am getting empty array like this?
[image]

Comment: Call the blade file with compact of that variable. In the blade use foreach to format accordingly

Comment: return view('pages/home_page_product',compact('main','products', 'profile', 'all_categories','count','procat','probrand'));

Comment: I passed like this. How to call in blade?

Comment: In the blade, use `foreach($all_categories as $category)` and process

Comment: I did it. But getting this error. htmlspecialchars() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given

Comment: So you want just `sub_categories` to be listed?

Comment: No. I want main category in one menu and the sub category in other menu like hovering main categories, I want to get sub categories

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Return the view blade along with compact of that variable:

```
return view('yourblade',compact('all_categories'));
```

Then in the blade file, use `foreach` to parse the sub-categories:

```
foreach($all_categories as $category)
```

---

**With formatting:**

```
@foreach($all_categories as $category) 
    {{ $category['name'] }} // Prints men,... - format with your 
    @foreach($category['sub_categories'] as $subcategory) {
        {{ $subcategory }}  // Prints all your sub-categories under men,...
    @endforeach
@endforeach
```

Comment: Everything perfect. Look at my updated answer. Am getting like that

Comment: Its the pluck that returns the array, use index to fetch `[0]` or `pop()` whichever you prefer

Comment: Yes. I did it. Thank you so much

Comment: Can you check my emptyness problem

Comment: Check if the array is not empty before processing your inner foreach

Comment: @if(!empty($category['sub_categories']))

Comment: I did it. Thanks.

Comment: $(".sub").filter(function() {
  return $.trim($(this).text()) == '';
}).hide();

Comment: with this function